# TcpListener Proxy HttpWeb

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm currently working on a project that requires piping some HTTP traffic through a local proxy, that my application has set up using a TcpListener. It's really a very basic setup.

I can get the standard header, an example from Firefox would be:

```
GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Now, I would like to see the conctents of example.com even though it went through my proxy. The solutions I have seen to this is to take these headers, and then just pass them through an HttpWebRequest. However, I don't seem to understand how you can pass an entire header.

If anyone has dealt with a situation like this before, or know how I can pass an entire header to an HttpWebRequest, it would be greatly appreciated.

I'm writing this in VB.NET by the way, but replies in either of the .NET languages is totally fine.

**EDIT:** I may have worded this a little confusing.

What I am getting is the request (header) that the website is passing along to the proxy. Then I read the stream from the TcpListener to get that header. Now, that stream contains a header as shown in the indented code box. Now, in order to write a response back to the stream containing the content that would normally be shown of no piping was done, I am thinking I'd have to take the header I collected, use an HttpWebRequest to get the content, then write that to the stream, to present the user with the intended webpage.

So what I am wondering is: How can I feed this header to an HttpWebRequest, and get content which I can then write to a NetworkStream, that'll then show up as normal in the browser. This is how I'd assume all proxies work, but perhaps not.

Answer (score 0):

Http headers are separated by colon and delimited by crlf. The header and the body are separated by an empty line.

Hence continue to read from the `TcpClient`/`Socket` until you receive an empty line. Then parse each header, look for Content-Length (to see if you should read a body too). Finally build a `HttpWebRequest` and send everything.

Once you receive a reply you need to read everything from the HttpWebResponse, build a valid HTTP response message and finally send everything back.

You could also take a look at my Apache licensed library which contains a HttpListener and a http encoder/decoder. http://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.framework.